# What did I do wrong in deploying Nuxt JS app?

Tags: linux, nginx, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have Nuxt JS app. It is successfully runs on my local machine from IDE and shows all resources.
The App is deployed here:
[glinka.tk](http://glinka.tk)

The application doesn't load resources(images, fonts, js files) when it is deployed on Linux server.
It shows error:
[image: error]

**What did I do wrong in deploy? How can I resolve errors and properly load all resources?**

All resources are loaded here:

[image: load resources]

I connect images like this:

```
<img src="../assets/images/my-works-bg.webp" alt="works-bg" />
```

I also tried this:

```
<img src="~/assets/images/avatar.webp" alt="" />
```

What I tried to do:

1. Cloned git repository to linux server
2. I installed all dependencies - `yarn install`
3. I built the project - `yarn run build`
4. I created nginx file config:

   ```
   server {

       listen 80;

       server_name glinka.tk  www.glinka.tk;
       index index.html index.htm;

       location /_nuxt/ {
           alias /home/kentforth/webapps/Glinka-Frontend-Nuxt/.nuxt/dist/;
       }
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:6050;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

       error_log  /var/log/nginx/glinka-frontend-error.log;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/glinka-frontend-access.log;
   }
   ```
5. I run the application using pm2 for node js apps:

   ```
   pm2 start npm --name "glinka-frontend" -- start
   ```

[image: pm2]

**EDIT:**
It seems browser try to get resources from another path that I do not have

Here is example for path to image from my project

```
<img src="~/assets/images/avatar.webp" alt="" />
```

I don't know why nuxt try to load image from /_nuxt/img folders. I do not have such folders. I have folder /assets/images for all images

Directory Structure on linux server in production:
[image: dir 1]

[image: dir 2]

Fonts are connected like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: local("Montserrat");
  src: url('../fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff') format("woff");
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Errors occurs only in production on linux server. I have no errors on my local machine and everything is fine.

Comment: Please share some code— for example, the reference to avatar.webp. You mention you use “~/images/avatar.webp” but your screenshot shows “/img/avatar.webp”. It’s very difficult to troubleshoot without knowing how your code is structured.

Comment: I made EDIT. What sxactly should I provide? I have a lot of stuff. Do you mean path to images and fonts?

Comment: In your nginx config, point to your project root instead of the /.nuxt/dist directory.

Comment: @Rob, sorry! I didn't know about that

Comment: @NickDawes, how can I do that? can you give me an example?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lukaszflorczak/2d79887c5825e99e94b26f09b9c44830 shows an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nick Dawes
I changed nginx config and it worked:

```
   server {

    listen 80;

    server_name glinka.tk  www.glinka.tk;
    index index.html index.htm;

    root /home/kentforth/webapps/Glinka-Frontend-Nuxt/dist;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:6050;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/glinka-frontend-error.log;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/glinka-frontend-access.log;
}
```